# React native local notifications

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications, expo

I am new to React Native and need to implement a functionality where the app needs to send the user a notification every day at a certain time. The data to be shown for each day is stored in a json file on the client side and will not change. The notifications are on a schedule. Given that I was hoping there could be a way to just trigger a notification from the app itself.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this without having to detach the app from expo? I can't use 'react-native-push-notification'without running react-native link and that requires me to detach the app. Is that right?

Is this possible?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with expo using the `scheduleLocalNotificationAsync` function (have a look at [these docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#notificationsschedulelocalnotificationasynclocalnotification-schedulingoptions) for more details). Make sure you have permission to send notifications first. Note that if the notification triggers when the app is in the foreground you won't see a notification but you can still listen to this event.

**i. Ask for permission**

```js
import { Permissions } from 'expo';

// ... somewhere before scheduling notifications ...
const { status } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
if (status !== 'granted') {
  await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
}
```

**ii. Schedule the notification**

```js
import { Notifications } from 'expo';

const notification = {
  title: 'Hi there!',
  body: 'Tap me to open the app.',
  android: { sound: true }, // Make a sound on Android
  ios: { sound: true }, // Make a sound on iOS
};

const options = {
  time: Date.now() + 10000, // Schedule it in 10 seconds
  repeat: 'day', // Repeat it daily
};

// ... somewhere after requesting permission ...
const id = Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync(notification, options)

// If you want to react even when your app is still in the
// foreground, you can listen to the event like this:
Notifications.addListener(() => {
  console.log('triggered!');
});
```

**iii. Cancel the scheduled notification**

You can use the returned id of the `scheduleLocalNotificationAsync` function to cancel the notification.

```js
import { Notifications } from 'expo';

// ... get the id of the scheduled notification ...

Notifications.cancelScheduledNotificationAsync(id)
```