# Scheduled Local Notification in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to issue Scheduled Local Notifications in order to remind user to do something even when the user is not working with the App. I want to do it in a React-Native app.

I checked the answers provided here but those answers are using Expo CLI Not React Native CLI.
[Local Schedule Notification react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092937/local-schedule-notification-react-native)
[React native local notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872678/react-native-local-notifications)
Also there are some packages out there like 'react-native-notifications' and 'react-native-push-notifications' on Github but I could not get a result from them. check them here https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification and here https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications
How should I issue a Scheduled Local Notification ?

```
NotificationsAndroid.localNotification({
    title: "Local notification",
    body: "This notification was generated by the app!",
    extra: "data"
});
```

Comment: Did you try the https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification package properly with a complete setup?

Comment: Hi, the error is this : https://ibb.co/4WtdMrC

Comment: You should follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64888995/20290021. You'll get your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use : 
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
                message: "Notification Message", 
                date: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 1000), // in 60 secs
            });

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-push-notification with specific time

```
  let now = new Date();
  now.setDate(now.getDate())
  now.setHours(15);
  now.setMinutes(58);
  now.setMilliseconds(0);
  PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    //... You can use all the options from localNotifications
    message: "My Notification Message", // (required)
    repeatType: 'day',
    date: new Date(now),
    allowWhileIdle: true, // (optional) set notification to work while on doze
  });
```