# Schedule local notifications in react native not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I am using `react-native-push-notifications` npm library to implement notifications feature in my app. However, I want to schedule the notifications and I am using `PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule` for doing so. But somehow it is not working when I am trying to trigger. I have pasted the code below. Someone could please help me with this I am new to this feature.

**event Handler**

```
const testPush = () =>{
      PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
        title:'My notification title',
        date:new Date(new Date().getTime()+3000),
        message:'My notification Message',
        allowWhileIdle:false
      });
    }
```

**Event trigger**

```
      <Pressable
        onPress={testPush}
        style={{ marginTop: 13 }}
      >
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#20232a', padding: 13, alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 10 }}>
          <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff' }}>Test push</Text>
        </View>
      </Pressable>
```

Comment: Is this happening on iOS or Android?

Comment: Hello Satheesh, It is happening in Android.

Answer (score 8):

You have missed the small thing in the documentation ( https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#readme ), since they have recently updated it
You have to create the channel for that.
Go through the documentation **https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#channel-management-android** for android only and in IOS ur code works fine

```
  PushNotification.createChannel(
{
  channelId: "channel-id", // (required)
  channelName: "My channel", // (required)
  channelDescription: "A channel to categorise your notifications", // (optional) default: undefined.
  soundName: "default", // (optional) See `soundName` parameter of `localNotification` function
  importance: 4, // (optional) default: 4. Int value of the Android notification importance
  vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true. Creates the default vibration patten if true.
},
(created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`) // (optional) callback returns whether the channel was created, false means it already existed.);
```

**NOTE: Without channel, notifications don't work**

Add below line in the schedule code

> channelId: "your-channel-id"

Add the code like below

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    title:'My notification title',
    date:new Date(new Date().getTime()+3000),
    message:'My notification Message',
    allowWhileIdle:false,
    channelId: "your-channel-id"
  });
```

Comment: or you can add
 <meta-data
      android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.default_notification_channel_id"
      android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
In AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Doesn't that negate the previous warning "Without channel, notifications don't work .... unless you use the default notification channel id"?

Comment: @ChandhanNarayanareddy for your suggestion to work, one must add 
 <string name="default_notification_channel_id" translatable="false">fcm_default_channel</string>
to their res > values > strings.xml file

Answer (score 3):

For me your sample code worked

[image]

So Make sure you have installed, given permissions and linked correctly.

(a) Check android/build.gradle has

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3')
        ...
    }
}
```

(b) Check In android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
  implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
  ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

(c) Check In MainApplication.java

```
import com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.ReactNativePushNotificationPackage;
```

(d) Check In android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml (Create the file if it doesn't exist).

```
<resources>
    <color name="white">#FFF</color>
</resources>
```

(e) Check In android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
.....
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application ....>
        <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground (remote-only, for local use ignoreInForeground) -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
                    android:value="false"/>
        <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                    android:resource="@color/white"/> <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->

        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
     .....
```

Comment: i was having issue with local scheduled notifications , adding *import com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.ReactNativePushNotificationPackage* this helped me to resolved
Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to wire up Firebase if you're not using Firebase

Answer (score 1):

adding `import com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.ReactNativePushNotificationPackage;`

did a trick for me, try adding this into your MainApplication.java

I was able to receive localNotification but it was only scheduled notifications those were not being received.

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. I wonder why they don't include this in the docs